# "To see life as fun and take it if we can"

Tags: idioms

In the Cranberries song "[Ode To MY Family](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/cranberries/odetomyfamily.html)" there's a line that I've always found curious. It reads "'Cause we were raised to see life as fun and take it if we can".

I'm not a native English speaker, but I don't think I've ever heard "to take life" in the meaning that seems to be intended here. On top of that, I know "taking a life" to be a common expression meaning to kill someone.

So my question is: does this line ring as morbid to a native English speaker as it does to me?

Comment: If you listen *very* carefully (I listened to two different singers), it's "take it if we *can't*".  "Take it" means "man up" and put up with stuff you don't like but can't change.

Comment: @hot-licks I don't hear any **can't** in this song. I just hear Dolores O'Riordan's  lilting affected singing-voice. And I see no reason to doubt the **can** in http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/cranberries/odetomyfamily.html

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't sound morbid to me.  In this context, I take it to mean, roughly:

> *See life as fun, and have as much fun as we can.*

I had a friend who used to say:

> *When offered a slice of life, take the big piece.*

It's a variant of, "*Grab a big slice of life!*"

Live large.  Seize the day.  See life as fun, and take it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I had always heard the line as “to see life as fodder”, which I thought was exquisitely poetic, and I was disappointed to learn that it is supposedly “to see life as fun”. I still hear it as “fodder”.

Answer (score -1):

It has been years since this was asked, but I was just listening to the song and it stood out to me in lyrics I looked up as well. But on listening closely the lyric seems to be "take it if we get", which fits with simple values. I think it's because it's supposed to rhyme with "damn" that this error is made. Either that or I am listening into it incorrectly and its really just like the last answer.

Another lyric like that is "Unhappiness, where's when I was young" (how it's shown on lyrics websites), which seems to me to need to be whereAS. Unhappiness... (existing adult situation), whereas when I was young [blah blah].